# Mac gcc doesn't allow calling std::string::~string explicitly

Tags: c++, macos

```
strdata->std::string::~string();
```

Here is the error I get:

```
error: '~' in destructor name should be after nested name specifier
        strdata->std::string::~string();
                              ^
```

I am using a cmake project... My gcc version installed via brew is following:

> gcc --version
>       Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>       Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
>       Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
>       Thread model: posix

I couldn't find the ~string() defined anywhere in the header files.  I ended up changing it as follows and that works.  It is ok for my use case for now.

```
strdata->std::string::~basic_string();
```

This original seems correct and works perfectly in GCC on Linux and CYGWIN.  What is the issue which is preventing it from working on mac?  Templates? Something else?

Comment: Calling the destructor seems generally wrong... Smells bad. (And yes, `std::string` is typically an alias for `std::basic_string<...>`.

Comment: I need to call the destructor because in this case I am doing my own memory management (ie via in-place new)

Comment: Would supplying an allocator not be a better choice? After all, that's what it is for...

Comment: [Works in GCC](http://ideone.com/xw67Y4), but that same code fails for me with clang with the OP's error message. I'm not sure which is right. Have a +1 for the interesting question.

Comment: Regarding allocators, both are valid options....

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Supplying a custom allocator is only useful if you want to manage the internal data allocated by the string. If you want to manage the string object itself (and its lifetime), then supplying a custom allocator won't help you. Even if a custom allocator is supplied, placement new may be desired. The two are, generally, orthogonal.

Comment: @Cornstalks, thanks.  I am new to mac development... how do I switch to GCC instead of clang?

Comment: Destructor lookup is all sorts of messed up, even in the standard.

Comment: You could install `gcc` via [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/). That's what I've done in the past. It takes forever to build, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer. For some reason, `using namespace std;` works, but without that `clang` fails. Consider this example:

```
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>

namespace foo {

struct A {};
typedef A A_t;

}

int main() {
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(foo::A)>::type storage;

    foo::A_t* obj = new(&storage) foo::A;

    using namespace foo; // Without this line, clang fails.
    obj->foo::A_t::~A_t();
}
```

Without the `using namespace foo;` line, clang will give an error `expected the class name after '~' to name a destructor`. But with that line, it works. Extending this to `std::string`:

```
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(std::string)>::type storage;

    std::string* obj = new(&storage) std::string;

    using namespace std; // Without this line, clang fails.
    obj->std::string::~string();
}
```

it works. It also works with the narrower `using std::string;`.

This doesn't answer the question of *why* `clang` fails. I don't know if it's a bug in `clang` or in `gcc`. But at least a workaround exists.

It may be worth reporting this as a bug in `clang`, and then letting them decide whether or not it really is a bug.

Comment: Thanks. Filing a bug with clang... They suggested https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5548  as an existing bug that is resolved fixed.   But that was in 2009.